# NuGet package for IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-core, nuget

I need to have access to `IFormFile` interface in ASP.Net Core 1.
Could you please tell me which NuGet package I should install?

Comment: Note that ASP.NET Core will go out of support end of June 2019. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/platform/support-policy/dotnet-core

Comment: Thank you ver much.
I personally prefer .Net Core 2, but the project uses 1. Anyhow I am going to share this with my colleagues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [API search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-1.0) shows it's part of 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.

However, the related NuGet package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
seems to be for newer .NET Core versions.

Answer (score 1):

> IFormFile Interface
>
> Definition Namespace: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http 
> Assembly: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Features.dll

From [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.iformfile?view=aspnetcore-1.0)

[Related Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http/1.0.0)

Answer (score 1):

Even though the original question is about ASP.NET Core 1, I landed here while searching for a way to reference IFormFile in a library targeting .NET 6 (should work for ASP.NET Core 3.0+). For those who are also looking for an up-to-date solution, you can add a FrameworkReference to your .csproj file like this:

```
<ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
</ItemGroup>
```

This will allow you to use IFormFile and other ASP.NET Core types in your library.

References:

[ASP.NET Core Fundamentals: Targeting ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/target-aspnetcore?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

[GitHub Issue: Reference to IFormFile in .NET 6](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/38329)

I hope this helps anyone who is working with a more recent version of .NET!